# In python Networkx, how to get paths from source to target of a graph by avoiding certain defined nodes?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I have a created a sample Undirected graph containing following below nodes using Networkx library in python.
nodes_connected  = [(4,1),(2,5),(5,1), (4,2), (5,6)]

I can  find All paths from node 6 to 4 using `nx.all_simple_paths(...),` ie
all_paths = [[6, 5, 2, 4], [6, 5, 1, 4]]

but now i have a requirement to to get all paths such that i have avoid paths contains node 1.
so basically i have to block paths when it reaches node 1, such that my paths shouldnot contain the node 1 even if there is a chance that a path exists through it.
ie, all_paths should now be
[[6, 5, 2, 4]].

can i get all paths that doesn't contain certain nodes ?
if yes, how to achieve it using Networkx?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a subgraph on the nodes leaving out `1` and then find paths in the subgraph.  Recent versions of networkx create the subgraph relatively efficiently.  They don't actually create a new graph, they create a 'view' of the original graph based only on the included nodes.  So your code would look like:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(4,1),(2,5),(5,1), (4,2), (5,6)])
nodelist = list(G.nodes())
nodelist.remove(1)
H = nx.subgraph(G)
print(nx.all_simple_paths(H,6,4))
> [[6, 5, 2, 4]]
```

Be a bit careful with views:

```
G.remove_node(5)
print(H.nodes())
> [4, 2, 6]
```

If I modify `G`, it affects `H`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Is this the only solution or can we provide any params to all_simple_paths() function to restrict certain nodes?

Comment: `all_simple_paths` takes the graph, the source, and the target as required arguments.  The only optional argument is a `cutoff`, which tells it how long of a path it is allowed to create.   So no, there's no such argument you can pass in.  There may be other ways to find these paths, but not by just adding an argument to `all_simple_paths`.